# Passing variables to external programs which require quotation marks

Tags: python, windows

When trying to call an external program with switches, I'm being held up with a program requirement for quotation marks.

An example of the code I've typed so far is this:

```
from subprocess import call

answer = raw_input("Please enter a variable.")

subprocess.call(["program.exe", "/f:", """answer""", "/s:", """answer"""])
```

However that doesn't work as subprocess will simply show `"answer"` rather than what the variable assigned to answer is.

The program itself requires `C:\program.exe /f:"test" /s:"test"`

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You need to escape the quote marks, not just use multiline strings

Comment: That was my first thought, however it runs into the problem described earlier: It will display "answer" instead of the variable that answer was assigned to.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the shell command as a single formatted string:

```
from subprocess import call

answer = raw_input("Please enter a variable.")
cmd = 'program.exe /f: "{0}" /s: "{0}"'.format(answer)
subprocess.call(cmd)
```

Comment: Thanks Colin, that works perfect! Still a novice and have been wracking my brain for a week trying to figure this out.

Comment: For cross-platform use `bin = 'program.exe';` `cmd = [bin, '/f:', answer, '/s:', answer]`, where `bin` will depend on the platform. On Windows, subprocess will convert this list to a command-line string, adding quotes when required according to the rules used by Microsoft's C/C++ runtime.